# How do I print each item of a Clojure vector that has been parsed to a JSON string?

Tags: clojure

My app's entry point reads from stdin, calls the logic layer to process the input, and returns the output as a JSON string (using the cheshire lib).

But currently, my output is a vector of JSONs, such as this:

```
[{"person":{"active":true,"age":41}},{"person":{"active":false,"age": 39}}]
```

And I need to print each JSON to the console in a separate line, such as this:

```
{"person": {"active": true, "age": 41}}
{"person": {"active": false, "age": 39}}
```

This is my current code:

```
(defn read-input! [file]
  (with-open [r (io/reader file)]
    (doall (map #(cheshire/parse-string % true)
                (line-seq r)))))

(defn input-received [input]
  (map logic/process-input input))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (cheshire/generate-string (-> args first read-input! input-received))))
```

I tried to do `(apply println (cheshire/generate-string (-> args first read-input! input-received)))`. But then each character was printed at each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than print the entire output vector as one JSON string, print each element of the vector separately:

```clj
(defn print-all [xs]
  (dorun (map (comp println cheshire/generate-string) xs)))
```

```clj
(print-all [{"person" {"active" true "age" 41}} {"person" {"active" false "age" 39}}])

;; prints the following:

{"person":{"active":true,"age":41}}
{"person":{"active":false,"age":39}}
```